# Permission denied with Firebase distribution android app using service account credentials mode

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-fabric, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to migrate from Fabric to Firebase since Fabric will not be available beyond March 31, 2020.

I already have done the first steps: adding plugins and dependencies to gradle, adding analytics json file, even crash reporting, and all seems correct because I can see data in the Firebase console (analytics and crashes).

But I'm not so lucky migrating the app distribution system from Beta+Fastlane to Firebase. I'm trying the option "*Distribute Android apps to testers using Gradle*". I've already added the plugin and the dependency and it is well added because I can run the gradle task `./gradlew appDistributionUploadMyVariant`.

I'm getting the `serviceCredentialsFile` from the Google Cloud Platform console for the user  called `firebase-adminsdk` (I think this name is given by the Firebase system) for the correct project. The email of the user is something like this `firebase-adminsdk-xxx@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, and it is the same as I can see in *Firebase console -> Settings -> Service accounts -> Firebase Admin SDK*.

I've downloaded the json file with the credentials and gradle can find it because if a put a wrong path-url intentionally for the file it logs a `Service credentials file does not exist`. The content of this file has the correct values for the `client_email` and `project_id` according to what I mentioned some lines above.

But I'm getting a 403 error. I paste some of the info I get if I execute the task `./gradlew appDistributionUploadMyVariant --info` (I've hide some private information):

```
Task ':app:appDistributionUploadMyVariant' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Found APK at /MyFolder/app/build/outputs/apk/qa/qaType/app-qa-qaType.apk.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...
Getting appId from output of google services plugin
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.28.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 808

curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.28.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' << $$$
Total: 808 bytes
grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N(...)
-------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: private
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 14:47:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Total: 207 bytes
{
  "access_token": "access_token_value",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
-------------- REQUEST  --------------
GET https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1alpha/apps/appId
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: <Not Logged>
User-Agent: Firebase App Distro Client/1.2.0
x-app-distro-api-client-id: com.google.firebase
x-app-distro-api-client-type: gradle
x-app-distro-api-client-version: 1.2.0

curl -v --compressed -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'Authorization: <Not Logged>' -H 'User-Agent: Firebase App Distro Client/1.2.0' -H 'x-app-distro-api-client-id: com.google.firebase' -H 'x-app-distro-api-client-type: gradle' -H 'x-app-distro-api-client-version: 1.2.0' -- 'https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/v1alpha/apps/appId'
-------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: private
Server: ESF
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Referer
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Origin
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2019 14:47:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Total: 126 bytes
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

:app:appDistributionUploadMyVariant (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 8,5,main]) completed. Took 1.552 secs.
AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-osx Daemon #0: shutdown

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadMyVariant'.
> App Distribution failed to fetch app information: [403] The caller does not have permission
```

I've also tried to pass the `appId` value from the gradle file with the same result.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error “[403] The caller does not have permission.” is caused by a permission issue. ​​​​​​​

Can you try to follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) on how to create service account and where to download the json, to see if it works?

You are also welcome to reach out to [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) with more info. :)

Comment: Thanks @Jing Li, it is working creating the service account like your proposed link. Thanks.

Comment: Firebase App Distribution says `Add the Firebase Quality Admin role` here [https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle#authenticate_using_a_service_account] which does not works. We have to add minimum role/rights as **Firebase Admin** to successful app distribution using gradle using command line.

Comment: Check https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/ . I think your role should be at least editor to get rid of this error.

Comment: stupid question but "add another role" doesnt contain **Firebase App Distribution Admin** when i try to filter the select box. I know the role exists in general but i cant select it. super weird.

Answer (score 1):

Please try running

```
firebase logout
```

and then login again (or use a token).

I had the same issue and followed all the other steps mentioned above to no success. However when I ran the `firebase appdistribution:distribute --debug foo` with the debug flag I noticed I was still logged in to another firebase instance, which seemed to cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The role for the service account would be: "Firebase App Distribution Admin SDK Service Agent":

> Read and write access to Firebase App Distribution with the Admin SDK

or as individual [permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions#app-distro).

Comment: i didn't find it in existing user. So, added a new user and this permission appeared there.. My deployment is working now. Thanks a lot.